# How to add your own .class into a compiled .jar file?

Tags: java

I have a .jar and I would like to add my own .class to it and recompile. Is there anywhere I can do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and it's simple (if you already have the .class file - then there is no recompilation).

(Assuming you have the .class file already and just want to add it to a .jar. If you don't have the .class file, you need to write a .java source file and compile it to .class first using javac)

Jar files are actually zip files - you can use zip/unzip to create and unpack them.

1. unzip the jar file using a unzip program
2. add your class to the unzipped directory (*)
3. zip again (possibly to another name.jar)

(*) In step 2, you **must** put your .class file in the **correct** directory -  correct meaning that the **package name** of your class must match the **directory path** where you .class file resides, **relative to the .jar archive root**.

For example if your **My.class** defines that it is in package **com.nicky**, then it must be found at **com/nicky/My.class** (where com is a directory in the archive root directory). If My.class has no package, they it must be in archive root directory.

No recompilation is needed - **Java does linking dynamically at runtime** - if the rest of the program needs to use class **com.nicky.My**, it will do so successfully if the class file is in the correct place in the .jar file.

You use the **classpath** parameter of the virtual machine (**java -cp a.jar:b.jar:...** ) to tell the java process where to look for classes - in case it would make more sense to package your class(es) in a separate .jar file..

--
Edit 1 / responding to your comment:
In case you a writing a new .java file, you need to first compile it into a .class using the **javac** command line compiler that comes with the jdk.

Every Java class belongs to a package, which is usually declared in the first line of the .java source file. Package names must match directory path location of the class (like in the example above), for both .java source files (for compilation to succeed), and for .class files (for dynamic loading / running to succeed).

You could also download and use a Java IDE (eg. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2 )to create your .class file. Create a new Java Project in Eclipse, write your class source code, click build (if it already doesn't build automatically) and then use a file explorer to take your .class file from the 'target' directory of the project on the disk.

If your new .java class depends on classes from the .jar you are trying to add it to, use

`javac -cp your.jar com/nicky/My.java`

to tell the compiler where the additional compile-time dependencies are.

If you are compiling from Eclipse, you need to configure that your project depends on your.jar: **Right Click on your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jars..**

Comment: Thank you for your swift and concise answer. Let's say I am writing a new .java file and I unzipped a .jar into a folder called A. Inside the A folder there is two folders: META-INF and org. In org there is files and I would like to place my .java into a folder call Drive. How do I then compile everything back into a .jar ?

Comment: You must compile the My.java source into a My.class file and then put the My.class file into A/package/name/of/your/My.class, and then zip folder A into a .jar file. (in the zip/jar there must be no 'A' folder - the A folder must be the archive root). 

Creating the .jar using zip is easy as there is no compilation involved - the tricky part might be compiling the .java into .class, depending on what dependencies  the new .java source code mentions/uses.

Comment: Hi Borut, I downloaded the Java IDE and tried compiling my .java into .class. I don't know which JARs are dependent so I added almost all. http://imgur.com/cCIVJAX here is kinda how it looks like. I then went to my workspace to copy the IsInBlackList.class and included it into the unzipped folder of that .jar file. After which I tried to look into the .jar file using JD gui, and it says IsInBlackList.class has // INTERNAL ERROR // there was no codes there.

Comment: So this is the path to my .class files: http://imgur.com/Zy9dn5V . I tried to just copy and paste into this path of the .jar file which is: http://imgur.com/6iQLAnf . This is not working. because after which JDgui shows that IsInBlackList.class has no codes but text // INTERNAL ERROR //. Can you please assist or help me?

Comment: Hi, to me everything looks fine in the images you posted, except that you should also copy the **IsInBlackList$1.class** into the .jar as well - because it contains the anonymous inner class from your code.

Comment: Excellent Answer Borut!