# How to add new class to Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Let's say there is a Maven dependency of my project and I want to add a new class to it in the existing package of the dependency. Is this possible? How do I do it without recompiling the dependency?

Example: I have a Java project TestJava and it has Maven dependency let's say apache commons-lang3 and I want to add a new class Test.java to package org.apache.commons.lang3 which is the package inside commons-lang3. How do I create Test.java in the current project and add it to the dependency?

This seems to be a good hack to do: [How to add your own .class into a compiled .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923887/how-to-add-your-own-class-into-a-compiled-jar-file)

Comment: What you see as benefit by adding a class to a dependency when you can add the package/class to your project itself. You even can create a new maven project with that class and apache-commons as dependency and when you add your new maven project as dependency you have that new class and apache-commons on your classpath.

Comment: Please reference this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923887/how-to-add-your-own-class-into-a-compiled-jar-file

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923887/how-to-add-your-own-class-into-a-compiled-jar-file This seems to be a nice hack. Pointed out by @AhahaGe

Answer (score 0):

If you've the .class files - then there is no need of recompilation.
unzip the jar -> add Test.java to the extracted part -> zip it back